# Banner Ad loading trouble in AdMob

Tags: android, admob

I was trying to integrate AdMob into my application. I am getting my banner ads in phone but it's not loading in tablet. Are there any specific settings for tablets?

Comment: No code? No exception? No logs?

Answer (score 1):

Use **DisplayMetrics** to get the width of the device, then a simply **if statement** that says if width is bigger then say 720 run advert with **tablet ad unit ID**, else run the **phone one**